# C++ - Standard Input Loop

Tags: c++, error-handling, istream

Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++* (2e, ch 10, print 6) gives the following idiom -- modified slightly to make it stand-alone and compilable -- for iteratively reading from an input stream until either EOF or a designated terminator character is encountered, with an exception thrown for any other stopping condition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::istream& is = std::cin;
    char term = '|';  // terminator

    for (int x; is >> x; ) {
        // do something with x
    }
    if (is.bad()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("bad input stream");
    }
    if (is.fail()) {
        is.clear();
        char c;
        if (!(is >> c && c == term)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("bad termination of input");
        }
    }
    // carry on: we found EOF or terminator
}
```

The program comments and surrounding exposition imply that EOF is an acceptable (non-error-causing) way for this iterative read to end. But when I test this on files such as the following two-line text file containing no terminators,

```
3 1 4 1 5
9 2 6 5 3
```

an exception is thrown ("bad termination of input"). An exception is what I would expect -- after reading the final '3', the subsequent read encounters EOF, causing the stream's eofbit to be flipped, but the read also failed, causing the failbit to be flipped. The idiom seems to assume that eofbit and failbit are mutually exclusive.

Is this idiom serviceable or does it have a logical error in how the EOF case is handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this state reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) the `failbit` is

> input/output operation failed (formatting or extraction error)

The reference also says `failbit` is set

> if either `eofbit` or `badbit` is already set on the stream, or if the end of stream is encountered while consuming leading whitespace

So encountering the end of the input itself doesn't set `failbit`, but attempting to read again will set `failbit`.

Comment: Given the structure of the input loop in the OP, wouldn't both eofbit and failbit always be flipped together? Under what circumstances would the given input loop not throw an exception upon encountering EOF?

Comment: @ColeArora It really depends in the input itself. From the quoted reference: "or if the end of stream is encountered while consuming leading whitespace". If the last line of input contains a newline then that's exactly what will happen. The last integer value is read, and the next iteration while skipping whitespace (which includes newlines) the end of the file is reached then certainly the `failbit` will be set. *But* if the last line doesn't have a newline at the end, then the last integer is read, the next iteration only the `eofbit` flag will be set.

Comment: The files I interact with usually have a newline terminating the last line, making the given input loop error out on encountering EOF (and making the idiom not exactly seem "general-purpose"). But I can see now how eofbit can be flipped without failbit coming along for the ride, thank you.